# trying to validate my radiobuttons. Can someone help me on my way?

Tags: javascript, html

I have struggeling with my problem for days now and cant find a solution.

Im trying to validate my Radiobuttons, when i submit the form i want it to validate if the radio buttons is empty and then add a is-invalid class from bootstrap, and if some of the buttons are checked i want it to add Class is-valid. When i submit the form right now it only adds class is-invalid.

HTML

```
<fieldset class="form-group col-md-6">
    <div class="col">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-md-6">NewsFrek </legend>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios1" value="option1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                    Every Week
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check col">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios2" value="option2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                    Every month
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios3" value="option3">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                    Every year
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

JavaScript

```
if(checkCheckBoxen.checked == true){
    $(checkCheckBoxen).addClass('is-valid')   
} else{
    $(checkCheckBoxen).removeClass('is-valid')
    $(checkCheckBoxen).addClass('is-invalid')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know if this solves your problem because I am not sure if I understand it.

HTML:

```
<fieldset>   
<div class="col">
                <legend class="col-form-label col-md-6">NewsFrek </legend>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios1" value="option1">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                      Every Week
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check col">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios2" value="option2">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                      Every month
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios3" value="option3">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                      Every year
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
<a href='javascript:;' class="btn btn-primary ml-5 mt-2" onClick='test()'>Submit Me</>
```

Javascript:

```
test = () => {
  $(".form-check-input").each(function(index, element) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (this.checked) {
          $(element).removeClass('is-invalid')
          $(element).addClass('is-valid');
        }else{
          $(element).addClass('is-invalid')
        }
   });
}
```

Here's [a codepen link](https://codepen.io/ekinalcar/pen/eYmggqy)!

Answer (score 0):

```js
        function display() {  
            if(document.getElementById('GFG').checked) { 
                document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML 
                    = document.getElementById("GFG").value 
                    + " radio button checked"; 
            } 
            else if(document.getElementById('HTML').checked) { 
                document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML 
                    = document.getElementById("HTML").value 
                    + " radio button checked";   
            } 
            else if(document.getElementById('JS').checked) { 
                document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML 
                    = document.getElementById("JS").value 
                    + " radio button checked";   
            } 
            else { 
                document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML 
                    = "No one selected"; 
            } 
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  
<head> 
    <title> 
        How to check whether a radio button 
        is selected with JavaScript ? 
    </title> 
</head> 
  
<body>  
      
    <h1 style="color:green;"> 
        GeeksforGeeks 
    </h1> 
      
    <h3> 
        Click on the button to check whether<br> 
        a radio button is sected or not 
    </h3> 
      
    <form> 
        <input type="radio" name="GFG" id="GFG"
            value="GeeksforGeeks">GeeksforGeeks<br> 
          
        <input type="radio" name="GFG" id="HTML"
            value="HTML">HTML<br> 
          
        <input type="radio" name="GFG" id="JS"
            value="JavaScript">JavaScript<br><br> 
      
        <button type="button" onclick="display()"> 
            Submit 
        </button> 
    </form> 
    <br> 
    <div id="disp" style= 
        "color:green; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold;"> 
    </div>  
</body>  
    
</html>
```

form validation before submitting the form, you can modify as you need